# Yii2 - Error #1 - An internal server error occurred

Tags: php, redirect, hyperlink, translation, yii2

**Greetings**

**I Have upload to a web server (not local) a Yii2 application into: http://acastro.wc.lt/**

**The problem is that when trying to switch between ENG or PT languages the framework thows an ERROR #1 - An internal server error occurred.**

In my Layout.php i have the following links inside the nav:: Widget:

```
'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
            'items' => [
                ['label' => 'ENG', 'url' => ['/site/langus'], 'visible' => Yii::$app->user->isGuest],
                ['label' => 'PT', 'url' => ['/site/langpt'], 'visible' => Yii::$app->user->isGuest],
```

And in my siteController i have the actions to switch between the languages that translate the application in real time:

```
public function beforeAction($action) {
    if (Yii::$app->session->has('lang')) {
        Yii::$app->language = Yii::$app->session->get('lang');
    } else {
        Yii::$app->language = 'us';
    }
    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}

public function actionLangus(){  
    Yii::$app->session->set('lang', 'us'); //or $_GET['lang']
    return $this->redirect(Url::toRoute(['site/index']));   
}

  public function actionLangpt(){  
    Yii::$app->session->set('lang', 'pt'); //or $_GET['lang']
    return $this->redirect(Url::toRoute(['site/index']));
}
```

**In my localhost machine installed by MAMP in my MAC OSX Yosemite the links work very well and change in realtime the application language, but in the live server the links ENG and PT throw ERROR #1.**

Perhaps there's a problem in my actions in the redirect expression's

```
Yii::$app->session->set('lang', 'pt'); //or $_GET['lang']
```

**Any ideas of what could be the issue causing this behavior only in live server? The PHP from the server is updated to one of the recent and last version's.**

Comment: Have you tried to turn YII_DEBUG on, to see a detailed error message?

Comment: Or simply enable error file logs ? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-logging.html

Comment: No. I don't. Good Suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: How to enable Yii2 Debug on live server? I'm reading the Yii2 api but as far as i can see it always teaches debug in YII_ENV_DEV.

Comment: There was already the problem:
 PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException
Class 'yii\helpers\url' not found

Perhaps you have to reinit the autoloader or you've forgot to deploy the files? Or you mixed lower and uppercase letters somewhere. That would explain, why it works on your local Mac but not on the server Linux

Comment: That problem is fixed now. I was messing trying to solve the link problem and generated this one :(

Comment: No. The upper or lower case doesn't seem to be the problem :(

Comment: Hmm, have you added the namespace to "Url"?

Comment: Yes i have all namespaces. Nevertheless the problem is now Solved with the below edit from Ali. Many thanks to Volker and Soju for trying to help.

Comment: Just a last question. Was your namespace yii\helpers\url or yii\helpers\Url?

Comment: It was in lower case -> yii\helpers\url.
Damn :((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the problem as everything looks ok. But make sure you do not have any short tags. You should have no `<?` except `<?=` and `<?php` . Usually local installs are more relaxed but short tags are turned off on the server.
**EDIT**
Also try return $this->redirect(['site/index']);